# Embedded framework in release mode only

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, carthage

I'm trying to track down a confusing xcodebuild issue.  I have a carthage dynamic framework project that includes another dynamic framework.  When I do a debug build (which seems to be what carthage does)

`xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator9.0  ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration release`

My resultant framework has a `/Frameworks` directory inside of it.

When I do a debug build this `/Frameworks` directory does not exist.  This is causing issues because you can't submit an app to apple that has embedded frameworks.

I'm sorry this question is a little open ended but does anybody have any ideas what settings I should be looking at in my build file?

When I did an `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` i see the following:

> FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH = GDL90.framework/Frameworks

Which I'm assuming is probably the culprit.  But i'm not sure how to fix/change this guy.  I'm assuming if i made it `GDL90.framework/../../Frameworks` that would likely get it outside of my framework - but .... a little unclear how to do this.